# swift compile error due to class extension

Tags: xcode, swift

I have been working on a project and everything seemed to work fine. I have added the following class extension:

```
extension CGFloat {
static func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UInt32.max))
}
static func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    assert(min < max)
    return CGFloat.random() * (max - min) + min
}
}
```

And I suddenly got 21 errors. The screen shot is below.
[image]

Anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT:

I managed to solve the problem, which apparently was that I should import UIKit above everything else. Now I still have a problem, that the app runs fine on a simulator but does not work on real device. It says that there is segmentation fault: 11, and that it cant build obj-c module UIKit.

Comment: Just addd your extension to one of my projects. It complies. 
Have you done all there rituals with clean build, deleted derived data, restarting Xcode? 

Otherwise it feels like some compiler settings.

Comment: I did. And now its even worse, even If I delete the extension I get 20 erros of that kind. Also, you know how you start typing a function and if it exists, it pop ups. Now it stopped doing that too.

Comment: Sound weird. Are you using some optimized libraries like cocos2d, or something doing stuff on low level? Thinking it might be some kind of 32-bit vs 64-bit thing?

Comment: I dont think so. I have not touched the standard xcode settings. The last error in my error list says "could not build objective - c module sprite kit". Maybe this helps?

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem for some time now. Sorry, no luck. But maybe you could try to remove your Frameworks from the build, and add them back. Or simply create a new project and move any source files over. See if its only something with the environment?

Comment: I edited the question, maybe you know whats wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

In the case adding UIKit started making things work. Could it be as simple as adding...

```
import Foundation
```

on the top would make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve it: All I needed to do was to reduce my deployment target from 8.3 to 8. No idea why this is the case though.